# Find average location of pixel of a given color

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am making an automatic curve detection program (graphs, 2D plots, etc.) and have gotten stuck with trying to find the average location of a color. The color is determined based on a K means clustering, so I have the RGB value for that color. I have also built a small sliding window program to follow a set of (X,Y) coordinates, and in that window is where the average location/centroid for a particular color needs to be found. I am very new to OpenCV, so I will detail what I want to do below, and appreciate any help.

1. Find the 3 most common colors with K-means and obtain the RGB values of those colors (done).
2. Use the sliding window to establish an N x N search window that rides along a determined X,Y path (done).
3. Apply a mask to get the curve color (based on Kmeans) extracted in the search window (need help). Also potentially mask out the background color based on Kmeans.
4. Find the average X,Y coordinate/pixel location for the desired curve color in the NxN search window (need help).

It would be appreciated if anyone could help with masking the color of the image based on the RGB value in OpenCV and then determining the average pixel location of the desired color in the search window. I have included the code that I have so far. The boundaries would come from the K-means clustering, but right now they are just hard coded for testing purposes.

Below is an example curve, where I would attempt to follow any of the black lines [image: Curve]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import math
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import ReadCoords
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

(winW, winH) = (12,12)
xs,ys = ReadCoords.read_coords()
image = cv2.imread(r"Curve.PNG")


boundaries = [([0,0,0],[128,128,128])]
def color_detection(image, boundaries):
  for (lower,upper) in boundaries:
      lower = np.array(lower, dtype = 'uint8')
      upper = np.array(upper, dtype = 'uint8')

      mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
      output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask = mask)
      return output

def kmeans_colors(image = image):
    org_clone = image.copy()
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))
    # image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 1))
    clt = KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
    clt.fit(image)

    # print(clt.cluster_centers_)

    def centroid_histogram(clt):
        # grab the number of different clusters and create a histogram
        # based on the number of pixels assigned to each cluster
        numLabels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(clt.labels_)) + 1)
        (hist, _) = np.histogram(clt.labels_, bins = numLabels)

        # normalize the histogram, such that it sums to one
        hist = hist.astype("float")
        hist /= hist.sum()

        # return the histogram
        return hist


    def plot_colors(hist, centroids):
        # initialize the bar chart representing the relative frequency
        # of each of the colors
        bar = np.zeros((50, 300, 3), dtype = "uint8")
        startX = 0

        # loop over the percentage of each cluster and the color of
        # each cluster
        for (percent, color) in zip(hist, centroids):
            # plot the relative percentage of each cluster
            endX = startX + (percent * 300)
            cv2.rectangle(bar, (int(startX), 0), (int(endX), 50),
                color.astype("uint8").tolist(), -1)
            startX = endX

        # return the bar chart
        return bar


    hist = centroid_histogram(clt)
    bar = plot_colors(hist, clt.cluster_centers_)

    return clt.cluster_centers_


def curve_sliding_window(image, step_size, window_size, x_range, y_range):
  for x,y in zip(x_range, y_range):
    yield (x, y, image[y:y+window_size[1], x:x+window_size[0]])


for (x, y, window) in curve_sliding_window(image, step_size=8, window_size=(winW, winH), x_range = xs, y_range = ys ):
    # if the window does not meet our desired window size, ignore it
    if window.shape[0] != winH or window.shape[1] != winW:
        continue


    # THIS IS WHERE YOU WOULD PROCESS YOUR WINDOW, SUCH AS APPLYING A
    # MACHINE LEARNING CLASSIFIER TO CLASSIFY THE CONTENTS OF THE
    # WINDOW

    # since we do not have a classifier, we'll just draw the window
    clone = image.copy()
    cv2.rectangle(clone, (x, y), (x + winW, y + winH), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Window", clone)
    # cv2.waitKey(1)
    # time.sleep(0.01)

    masked = color_detection(window, boundaries)

    cX,cY = moment_centriod(contours(window))

    if cX != 3 and cY != 3:
        cv2.circle(window, (cX, cY), 1, (0,0,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow("windows", np.hstack([masked, window]))
    cv2.waitKey(50)
```

Comment: You can use scikit-learn kmeans and get the cluster centers directly. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html. Likewise in Python/OpenCV see https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html

Comment: Please share images corresponding to last step you completed successfully and code you are stuck with going to next step. Thank you.

Comment: You want to follow the solid black lines, or the dashed grey ones? How big is a window in "pixels wide by pixels tall" please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to follow the black lines. Ideally the window would be adjusted to the width of the line. Currently the first step is to click a few points on the line, which is then loaded with ReadCoords. Then the search window "rides" that line and uses the kmeans color to find the average location of a pixel color (black in this case).

Comment: Can you share some sensible coordinates you have been using?